# DVWP: How can i hide group header row?

Tags: data-view-web-part

We use SharePoint and DVWP for getting items from InfoPath Form library. In DVWP we enabled 4-level grouping. And rows with group headers looks like this:

- Month: Value

  - Type: Value

    - Category: Value

      - Subcategory: Value

And this looks good except behavior when one of grouping fields contains blank values. In this case - we can see expanded grouping rows with group headers which looks like "field_name: " except "field_name: value".

Is it possible (with jQuery or with XSL) to hide this rows (which contain group header with blank field value) from DVWP?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you just want to remove the grouping header row and not the items in the grouping. I think that addressing this directly in XSL would be the best way. In your XSL template, add a validation against the group field value (should be $fieldvalue)

You can put this in your specific grouping template :

```
<xsl:if test="$fieldvalue != ''"> <!-- grouping header --></xsl:if>
```

or in the body template :

```
<xsl:if test="$groupheader0 != ''"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.groupheader0">
    <!-- params -->
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

**Before**

Month: July

Type:

Item1

**After**

Month: July

Item1